# Why does my laravel eloquent queries' memory usage go to infinity?

Tags: php, laravel

I have php 8.2 with xdebug and laravel 10. I upgraded from laravel 8 to 10. I have zero entries in the database.

When I make a simple Eloquent query such as;

```
Member::whereMonth('created_at', '=', $startDate->month)->whereYear('created_at', '=', $startDate->year)->count();
```

php8.2 takes forever to complete the request and memory increases second by second until it shutdowns because memory overlimit. this is same for every Eloquent request.

What could be the reason for this?

I changed

```
Member::whereMonth('created_at', '=', $startDate->month)->whereYear('created_at', '=', $startDate->year)->count();
```

to

```
Member::all();
```

Everything goes well.

Comment: Is your startDate->year is already a carbon instance? If not then try to cast with. I am not entirely sure that it would work though.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason.

use Eloquence; directive inside models makes the problem. Removing it fixes the problem.